# LSTM predicting same word repeatedly

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I am sure that this has happened to you if you have trained an LSTM model. The LSTM model predicts the same word 2 or 3 times. Now, I am not saying that for every input it has the same output. I am saying that for  every input,  the output that it produces has some repeated words in it. For example:

```
    Human: What do you like?
    Bot: I quite enjoy enjoy programming!
```

Here the bot outputted the word enjoy 2 times. Not only in chatbots, I have encountered this issue in every LSTM Model I have trained so far.

What could be the reason of this? And how to stop this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are downvoting my question, then please mention the reason of downvoting in comments, so that I can do my best to improve it!

Comment: You may force your LSTM structure to avoid repeated words in sequence. By checking the last outputted word or by modifying your last layer.

Comment: I think you should continue training the model a bit more or use more data, as it needs to fix this repetition issue.